# How to set default 'Image' on database class properties with Fluent API in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, code-first

I'm trying to set a default 'Image' on code first properties in my DBContext and need to use dependency injection to add 'IHostingEnvironment' to have the root path. How can I add 'IHostingEnvironment' to my 'OnModelCreating()' to access the path to find my images in directories and set them as default value on a specific property of my database class?

I'm using Asp.net core 2.2, and couldn't find my answer

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder,IFormFile img)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(builder);
   builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
   { 
      ...
      byte[] b = new byte[img.Length];
      img.OpenReadStream().Read(b, 0, b.Length);
      p.img = b;
      entity.Property(b => b.UserImage).HasDefaultValue(b);
      ...
   });
}
```

I want that anytime that new user signup into my website, automatically system sets a default (and random) image for him and store it in the database without repeating the codes of reading and writing images in arrays.
something like the code that I have written above.

Comment: I fail to see why it would repeat code if you don't do it in `OnModelCreating`. It would typically be code for a service or a utility class. Anyway, `OnModelCreating` isn't the right place because that's a one-time configuration for the life-time of an application.

Comment: Also, `HasDefaultValue`, i.e. a database default, means: one and the same value for each new record, unless overridden in the insert statement. Your *random* "default image" is quite different from a database default.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is define a default value for some column in your database, the best aproach would be set in the class constructor, so that's way when your application create an entity of that class this one already have the default value.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, `HasDefaultValue` would not work. For `HasDefaultValue`, it will generate the default value when you add migration like:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
        name: "UserImage",
        table: "Products",
        nullable: true,
        defaultValue: "Test2");
}
```

If you prefer setting default value with `IHostingEnvironment`, you could try override the `SaveChanges` like

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
        IConfiguration configuration
        , IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        : base(options)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {            
        foreach (var entityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entityEntry.Entity is Product product && product.UserImage == null)
            {
                product.UserImage = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + new Random().Next(10).ToString();
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is about 'OnModelCreating' method that allocates default value on any fields of database that we wish. for instance in that function we can allocate getdate() to a specific field that anytime a new record we add, automatically it adds the current datetime of the server in that field. sample code:
.
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .Property(b => b.Created)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }

Comment: @saeedsp It's impossible to use `IHostingEnvironment` in HasDefaultValueSql. For `getdate()`, it's a function in sql database and it will generate value for `Created` in the sql server. But currently, you are trying to use `IHostingEnvironment` which is only available in asp.net core. For `HasDefaultValue`, it will set the same value for all new records.